# BLU G71+ G0570WW stuck in bootloop and won't boot into recovery nor download mode

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, android-11, blu

I just got BLU G71+ (G0570WW) and from the beginning, I've had problems. It was getting super hot and would just shut off out of the blue. My cousin (who is usually good with phones and computers, etc.) said if I root it, that would fix it. I don't know how, so I gave it to him, and now it's worse than it was before.

He said he unlocked the bootloader, got a ROM for my phone (something about magic?), put it in fastboot, and ran

```
fastboot flash boot_a boot.img
fastboot flash boot_b boot.img
fastboot reboot
```

at which point apparently my phone started flashing on and off, on and off, and it continues to do so. Anytime I turn it on, I have to disconnect the battery.

Please tell me this can be fixed because apparently from what I have read, he voided my warranty when he unlocked the bootloader. And it doesn't respond to power + vol up nor power + vol down. Please help. He said it's a Unisoc T610, whatever that means.

---

Sidenote: is it normal that in my phone settings, my phone is G0570WW, but on the little sticker with the IMEI codes, it's G0571WW?